# Can not get com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer class

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to integrate Android plugin to unity3d, and call Android function like below:

```
AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
jo.Call("startLocationService");
```

The same as the unity3d official document's example code.
But in runtime, I can not get UnityPlayer's reference, so can not get the static vairable:
currentActivity, like this question:
[Android Plugin for Unity giving errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010398/android-plugin-for-unity-giving-errors)

Could anyone give help, thanks first.

Comment: It's because the above code can not run on unity editor, must be true android phones?

Comment: I got it, the above code must be run on android phone, unity editor can not work.

Comment: Since you found out the solution to problem, please post it as an answer.